# How assign a value type to a generic key type of an object in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, type-inference, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function that merges, and sorts already sorted arrays into one sorted array. It accepts array of array of objects, and a key to compare which will be the base of the comparison. I need to make sure that the value of the provided key is always a number.

Here's what I'm at so far:

```
const sortMerge = <
  A extends Array<I>,
  K extends keyof A[number],
  I = A[number] & {
    [key in K]: number;
  },
>(
  arrays: A[],
  key: K,
  sortMethod = SortMethod.asc,
) => {
  const indexesOfArrays = arrays.map(() => 0);

  const mergedSorted = [];

  while (arrays.some((array, i) => array.length > indexesOfArrays[i])) {
    const currentItemsOfArrays = arrays.map(
      (array, arrayIndex) => array[indexesOfArrays[arrayIndex]],
    );
    const comparison = currentItemsOfArrays.map((item) =>
      item ? item[key] : (sortMethod === SortMethod.asc ? Infinity : -Infinity),
    );

    const nextArrayIndex = comparison.indexOf(
      Math[sortMethod === SortMethod.asc ? 'min' : 'max'](...comparison),
    );
    const nextItem = currentItemsOfArrays[nextArrayIndex];

    mergedSorted.push(nextItem);
    indexesOfArrays[nextArrayIndex]++;
  }
  return mergedSorted;
};
```

Everything's fine, but it doesn't recognise `I[K]` as `number`, but that's what I was trying to do with defining both `K`, and `I` as generics.

What am I doing wrong?

Expected errors/types:

```js
const missingKey = [ { a: 1 } ];
const valid = [ { a: 2, b: 3 } ];
const anotherValid = [ { c: 3, b: 4 } ];

sortMerge([missingKey, valid], 'b') // missingKey[number] is missing property 'b';
sortMerge([valid, anotherValid], 'b') // expected return type: ({ a: number, b: number } | { c: number, b: number })[]
```

Comment: please provide more information about generic constraints. What you excpect to be `A`, `K` and `I`?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed generic constraints a bit:

```js
enum SortMethod {
  asc = 'asc',
}
const sortMerge = <
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Elem1 extends Record<Key, number>,
  Elem2 extends Record<Key, number>,

  Arr1 extends Elem1[],
  Arr2 extends Elem2[],
  Arrays extends [Arr1, Arr2]
>(
  arrays: [...Arrays],
  key: Key,
  sortMethod = SortMethod.asc,
): (Arrays[number][number])[] => {
  const indexesOfArrays = arrays.map(() => 0);

  const mergedSorted = [];

  while (arrays.some((array, i) => array.length > indexesOfArrays[i])) {
    const currentItemsOfArrays = arrays.map(
      (array, arrayIndex) => array[indexesOfArrays[arrayIndex]],
    );
    const comparison = currentItemsOfArrays.map((item) =>
      item ? item[key] : (sortMethod === SortMethod.asc ? Infinity : -Infinity),
    );

    const nextArrayIndex = comparison.indexOf(
      Math[sortMethod === SortMethod.asc ? 'min' : 'max'](...comparison),
    );
    const nextItem = currentItemsOfArrays[nextArrayIndex];

    mergedSorted.push(nextItem);
    indexesOfArrays[nextArrayIndex]++;
  }
  return mergedSorted;
}

const missingKey = [{ a: 1 }];
const valid = [{ a: 2, b: 3 }];
const anotherValid = [{ c: 3, b: 4 }];

sortMerge([missingKey, valid], 'b') // missingKey[number] is missing property 'b';
const x = sortMerge([valid, anotherValid], 'b')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg9gJwC4FlhIBZwCZQN4BQUUAhgM4DGUAvFAOTkV0A0BAvgRXCGUlGYlTAEAc2A0oAHiJQA0sACeUYAA8kobGSgAFBHAAOwpAvkLWxAKIAbYBACMytRq0AlYFwTZJp5lHAQAI2EAPnMoa1sAJkd1EE0oNw8vHz9IIIRQghkAQQQEB1VY+Ij7AG0AXTDchGjC53CbCEiKqrySBS06uK1S6rtfasjygmCAChkSNo6ALihSgDpF6vaySpkAa0VZnxkBZDRMHAl4ffQsbHnGVgBKWdHljtL-dPKntOFy64qaYPwZLh4fAAlnFVMAyAB5ABmDy0tEmCBW8wgJH0o1G1x+UAADNcANxZYgA3hQCDCMTYE7qXC0CoEmQAdwwQJsUFGCKRAjJ6I5ZigQMx1F+vPmNhAIkwUF+IOwYMhMKmZFKQM+mMIxCJ3BJFDAeVASAAkuoIPLYRJeWRkajxhqNeypr5eQbQSpBcKpsqXeDobDSk6XeU1rb8TJNYCoFwIPpJkCBCAJDq9SBDcbTYqrWjRkDjW7Qxrs7YoAB+fnG0qbBTlKB3PZCQ406i0KkHc6XSjFqDOqEg7NKWYAWi7PeM1zCxBDeeJfBAhQeztlKgTcCjMbj8xlqmhNttUBQJEwpVrLaOjabgmPF0YHboEBBdGr9BRKjo5VGi3mkejCFj3FHeZDtpTn4hRGoWtCJgg+qgSaPqKk8s5TPOqjlPStpkqIwCUoImHzPoYBkBgowzmo0EAfmXppoijzEUgc4BgA1PRBLEBwxCQUgurxuhFJUphBIcJwWp8LeZBkCCIimBIpR4KQswOGwKGCeGABuJBWECNJzDJJCzJEvgBLMADMUAKQSQEkCAcCYMIABqakaVJMkUEZ+mzAALCZikEEe5LAKMpQiWJ4opKp6nYJU9ABHQmIAPQxaSsZBRJihvIEHz8logXiVA+h6IYyBKHQUVmUJUCLrQPkYf5oUaY6lnWQgdlhRFRXRUAA)

If you want to infer keys of nested object or object in the array, you should start from the bottom.

**`Key`** - infered property of object

**`Elem`** - infered object where keys are `Key`

**`Arr`** - infered array of `Elem`

**`Arrays`** - infered array of `Arr`

As you might have noticed, I have started from infering the bottom level of prop and finished infering the top argument.

If you are interested in type inference on function arguments, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: It does work, but it doesn't preserve the correct type of the elements in arrays. It thinks every element is an object with a `Key` which value is `number`. I want it to preserve the original types, just make sure that the provided `key` exists on each objects, and it's a `number`.

Comment: Please provide valid and invalid scenarious

Comment: Please see updated question, and let me know if needs more information.

Comment: @GergőHorváth I made an update.

Comment: Actually `
  Arrays extends Arr[],
  Arr extends Elem[],
  Key extends PropertyKey,
  Elem extends Record<Key, number> = Arrays[number][number],`
solved the problem, accepting any number of arrays, and preserving the types correctly.